# is there chatbot engine or library support multiple bot creation and intercept

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, chatbot, agent

Currently , i'm looking for open source chatbot engine or chatbot framework that support creation of multiple bot(and it features). can someone give me any suggestion ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[API.AI](https://api.ai) allows you to create as many bots (API.AI calls them agents) as you want.  API.AI also has [integrations with 14 platform major chat and voice platforms including the Google Assistant, Facebook Messenger, Slack, and Alexa](https://api.ai/docs/integrations/) and [16 open source SDKs to integrate into your own apps](https://api.ai/docs/sdks).

Once API.AI has classified the user's intent and extracted any parameters from a user's query API.AI send structured data with the [intent](https://api.ai/docs/intents), [parameters](https://api.ai/docs/entities) and other information you may need to fulfill the user's request to any URL you specify with [API.AI's fulfillment webhook](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment).  This means you can use any server that can send and receive JSON.

Comment: Thanks Mate :D , it's really help me